Error when creating a project using Word VSTO Template
[![enter image description here][1]][1]I receive the following exception when creating a project using the Word VSTO Template in Visual Studio 2022.

Microsoft Visual Studio
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A1066
Any clues?
Thanks
Rajesh
I have included an image which shows the error
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/p7wIGSfg.png
